# Compare protocol in Swift class hierarchies

Tags: swift, swift2, protocols

I have a hierarchy of 2 Swift classes and need them to implement `Comparable`:

```
class Thing : Comparable {
    var name = "Thing"
    init(name : String){
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Thingy: Thing {
    override init(name: String){
        super.init(name: "Thingy")

    }  
}
func ==(lhs: Thing, rhs:Thing)->Bool{
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}
```

To comply with `Comparable`, I need to implement this function:

```
func <(lhs: Thing, rhs: Thing) -> Bool{
    return lhs.name < rhs.name
}
```

So far so good, but what happens if I need a specific < function for different subtypes, such as:

```
func <(lhs: SubThing, rhs: Thing) -> Bool{
        return lhs.name < rhs.name
    }
```

How am I supposed to do this? The compiler seems to ignore this last declaration.

Will it also work if the types are inverted?

```
lhs: SubThing, rhs: Thing
```

instead of

```
lhs: Thing, rhs: SubThing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the `<` operator should take the most specific match, so in your case

```
func <(lhs: Thing, rhs: Thing) -> Bool {
    print("Base");
    return lhs.name < rhs.name
}

func <(lhs: Subthing, rhs: Thing) -> Bool {
    print("Child");
    return lhs.name < rhs.name
}

Subthing(name: "a") < Thing(name: "b")
```

should print `Child`, however this doesn't happen.

Overloading using generics seem to work though:

```
func < <T1:Thing, T2: Thing>(lhs: T1, rhs: T2) -> Bool {
    print("Base");
    return lhs.name < rhs.name
}

func < <T1: Subthing, T2: Thing>(lhs: T1, rhs: T2) -> Bool {
    print("Child");
    return lhs.name < rhs.name
}

Subthing(name: "a") < Thing(name: "b")
```

correctly prints `Child`.

It seems that generic overloading has better type matching than the basic overload.

Answer (score 2):

Generics to the rescue. Make your `Equatable`, `Comparable` functions generic.
Constrain `T` to be a subclass of `Thing`.

```
func ==<T:Thing>(lhs: T, rhs:T) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}


let a = Thing(name: "alpha")
let b = Thingy(name: "beta")

a == b // false
```